# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE?

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run an android app from eclipse I meet this error and my app does not start:

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE
>
> Please check
>
> logcat output for more details. Launch canceled!

But when I opened logcat, I see that logcat doesn't print anything.

I think that some problem with my manifest file. so here is my manifest file:

> android:installLocation="preferExternal">>
>
> ```
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
>
> <application
>
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:debuggable="true" >
>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".HelloWorld"
>         android:label="Test" >
>
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>
>
>     </activity>
> </application>
>
> <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>    
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Is your Phone connected via USB? if yes, the SDCard is not mounted. Try to connect your phone in another mode or copy your software apk onto the SDCard, disconnect it from the pc and run the installation. It should work then :-)

For example, my Motorola Defy supports the usb modes "mass storage mode" and "media server" mode. In mass storage mode, the sdcard is unmounted from the device, so you can access it from your pc.

The problem is the "preferExternal" command, which tells Eclipse to try the installation on SDCard.
You can also try to erase the installLocation command to install it your app in internal storage.

Greetings!

Comment: No. I'm using Android  Emulator only. as I say in tag :)

Comment: Ok, is a sd card installed in your virtual device? ;-)

Comment: for others that use HTC phone for test,you can put it on charge only mode when connect to pc

Comment: In my case I had to add 
        android:installLocation="preferExternal"
into the manifest :S
Kind of absurd solution but it works.

Answer (score 19):

It's can be because  of low memory. For me problem solved when delete some unnecessary files and apps.

Comment: Thank you android for your amazing error messages. Because "NO SPACE AVAILABLE" is too mainstream

Answer (score 18):

1. Go to `cmd`
2. `cd` to `android sdk folder > platform tools`
3. Enter `adb shell`, now a `#` sign appears
4. Enter `pm set-install-location 1` and another `#` appears should work fine with you.

Note: The `1` in the pm command signifies that apps will install only on the internal storage. See [pm command](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. I get this INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE after its been working normally for about 10 application runs. I used to have to reboot the phone but this cmd appears to fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed my problem! I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and it doesn't use the 16GB USB internal storage. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to use: pm setInstallLocation 1 as set-install-loaction gave access denied. Thanks though, this put me on the right track.

Comment: `Enter adb shell, now a # sign appears` - only if the phone is rooted. Otherwise, `permission denied`

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 2000

Comment: unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for me since one of my devices (ZTE ZMax2) is not rootable. Ideally, I'd want a solution that doesn't require root access anyway.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the solution was to **restart** the phone.

Comment: Tjis can happen when android studio tries to uninstall the current app but the device tells adb that the app is still installed, so restarting the devide does solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

i solved it by adding the following line to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file in your app:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

...it should be like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MyTestApp"
android:installLocation="auto"
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case

1 - uninstall some Useless/low use apps

2 - clear ram memory

Answer (score 1):

My case worked after I deleted some files or apps on the phone. I use an Htc phone I think the phone needs some amount of space to be available on the internal memory, and the amount of space needed varies from phone to phone

Answer (score 1):

[image]If none of the fixes above worked for you, like it didn't for me, there's a really simple fix you could consider.

In your USB computer connection settings, uncheck the "Mount SD card" box and leave it only checked at "Media device (MTP)". Then run the app again.

This way your external storage won't be unmounted when you connect your device to your pc and your app will then install successfully

Answer (score 0):

this worked for my device: I had tried installing the apk through various means (adb install, installing it using the installer app, as well as the advice here) only to find that the solution was related to an app called Twilight, which once uninstalled, I was able to install apks again.  I found the solution [here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-2012-rooting-roms-hacks/286111-cant-install-apk.html).  If anyone can shed light on how an app can block installs like this did, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Insert memory card in your phone if not work then root your phone it will definitely work.