# eclipse running android app fails on "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE"

Tags: android, eclipse

This doesn't happen all the time.

I run my app from within eclipse as Right click>Run As>Android Application

I send my app successfully to the phone maybe 2 or 3 times, then all of a sudden it starts throwing this error. It appears the only resolution is to reboot the phone. Its extremely annoying and would really like some assistance on a permanent fix.

I'm using a windows 7 pc, usb cable, Samsung galaxy SII. 
Android Build: v21.1.0-569685

Full Console error dump

```
Android Launch!
[2013-02-15 15:36:50 - myapp] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-15 15:36:50 - myapp] Performing com.myapp.myapp.myaptivity activity launch
[2013-02-15 15:36:54 - myapp] Uploading myapp.apk onto device '0019dxxxxxxxxx'
[2013-02-15 15:36:58 - myapp] Installing myapp.apk...
[2013-02-15 15:36:59 - myapp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE
[2013-02-15 15:36:59 - myapp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-02-15 15:37:00 - myapp] Launch canceled!
```

I have read the suggestions on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273766/828395 
I dont have an internal memory card, I have 300mb free space. the phone does a weird thing where its usb drive appears to be always available within windows, but not quite. so if I delete a file from the connected drive, the phone screen changes and goes into USB mode, then out of it again. Refreshing the phone folders is a separate annoyance I have as it doesn't seem to be obvious.

would love to get this sorted as its costing me lots of time in rebooting. so any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was due to a faulty USB Cable. I have a cable which has a bare sheath at one end, and when I use this cable I get about 2-4 uses via Eclipse then it blows the failed media error. other cables appear to be consistently ok!

So if you arrive here, check your USB Cable and USB Connections!

Comment: In my case, I just uninstalled the app from the smartphone and the error message is gone.

Answer (score 1):

It works also clears the problem sometimes if you uninstall the app before running. (I think it somehow gets locked :/ )

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solved it with the following....

Add the following line to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file in your app:

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

...it should be like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MyTestApp"
android:installLocation="auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked when I used:

android:installLocation="internalOnly"

in the manifest file