# Error of build&run for my android device in Unity3d

Tags: android, build, sdk, unity-game-engine

I can't build & run my game on my android device. I have this error in the console. How can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273526/installation-error-install-failed-media-unavailable

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has a sdcard slot (and you haven't put in the sdcard) you would get this error. 
Try doing a build (not build and run) and then copy the apk to device store using any explorer (eg. android file manager).