# How to make a layout which has some questions and some radio buttons for it and we have to swipe it

Tags: android

Basically I am saying that I want to make an quiz app which have some questions and some options with radio buttons so what I want is that every questions appears and after that when I swipe the screen next question comes and when I swipe back previous question come and how to store questions and basic structure of how to make an app like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created something very similar in our business app. My solution was (as we used server to "generate" question) to build each question from components. Each component is of a type (let's say title, radio buttons, input field) and then I built each question using a `LinearLayout`. Adding components in a vertical `LinearLayout` as I got them from server in a `JSON` list. You just have to define data you will receive.

About the first part, how to show those questions. My solution was to create a `ViewPager` of custom `Fragments`. I used one `Fragment` per question which is able to render a question of a given data and manage user interactions. If you want to show user previous and next quesion you can use negative margin on `ViewPager`. You can find some documentation on [CommonsWare's blog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html).

If you define questions in a similar way as we did, and want to store them locally you can store them as a JSON in `SharedPreference` or you can use database for that. Probably `SharedPreferences` will be the easiest option for you. You don't really have to use JSON, you can use any type of format you can read/write.

Comment: Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273526/installation-error-install-failed-media-unavailable

Comment: can you please tell me how to store the questions and ans to the questions in the sqlite database ?

Comment: the easiest way is to use an ORM, one of the simplest is [SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) (you also have many other options). Other way is to start with "stock" [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Comment: I have to store the results of the radio buttons but when the user went back on question 1 after selecting answer for some questions so how to update values in database for this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Google search?

There are tons of tutorials out there to help you get started.  Grab something simple to get started with and then add the features you need.

Swiping back and forth is done with a [View Pager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

You can store the questions and answers with [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Good Luck