# Viewpager adapter code

Tags: android

I have made a simple app which will display some questions and I have used View pager adapter and for each question I have made fragment but my code is showing this error when I am running it

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE. It
>   is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: Similar to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273526/installation-error-install-failed-media-unavailable

Comment: Your question title really has nothing to do with the question itself. If you have a "simple app", then what information do you have to lose?